# Mockito mocking when() for two generic methods of different types

Tags: java, generics, mockito

I have two generic objects of class `Generic<T, R>`:

```
Generic<TypeA, TypeB> genericOne;
Generic<TypeB, TypeC> genericTwo;
```

I have to mock:

```
when(someObject.someMethod(Matchers.<Generic<TypeA, TypeB>>any()))
                .thenReturn(responseOne());

when(someObject.someMethod(Matchers.<Generic<TypeB, TypeC>>any()))
                .thenReturn(responseTwo());
```

The problem is that mockito will not the see difference between this two method calls because of type erasure - it's both recognized as `Generic<T, R>` class.

Is there any way to to distinguish between this two method calls?

Comment: you can use `thenAnswer` instead of `thenReturn` and implement anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mockito doesn't know which generics was specified in front of `any()` invocation and anyway it doesn't matter.

The parameters expected in the recording a mock behavior has to rely on :

- value (in terms of `equals()`
- or in terms of captor if `equals()` is not adequate
- or `any()` if the value of the parameter in the mock invocation doesn't matter or is not known in the test fixture

These never have to rely on the generic specified on.

To have a good example, look at `Mockito.anyCollectionOf(Class<T> clazz)` or `Mockito.anyMapOf(Class<K> keyClazz, Class<V> valueClazz)`.

These methods know the class passed but anyway, their specifications state :

> This method *don't do any type checks*, it is only there to avoid
>   casting in your code. This might however change (type checks could be
>   added) in a future major release.

Generally what you want to check is that the method to mock was invoked with the expected parameter and not any parameter : so `any()` will never achieve it.
**So trying to check only the generic type but accepting any values as parameters seems be an anti pattern mocking.**

In your case, if `equals()` is not convenient for the matching in the `when()` recording, use Mockito captor with `verify()` and do the check after the execution of the mock.

Comment: You are welcome. Beyond a specific workaround that could not be fine, I preferred to provide a broader idea on how to mocking with expected parameters because the person that codes a feature is the best one to decide which strategy chooses according its use case.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible to differentiate between the two as generic types are arased. But there are other options.

You can couple this calls to specific order so that even if mockito cannot differentiate between them it return expected value. This is done by chaining the `thenReturn` methods. First call returns `responseOne()` and second call returns `responseTwo()`.

```
when(someObject.someMethod(Matchers.<Generic<TypeA, TypeB>>any()))
    .thenReturn(responseOne())
    .thenReturn(responseTwo());
```

But this is not optimal as this test will break if your implementations changes. So here comes the second option.

You can implement custom [Fake](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2014/05/14/TheLittleMocker.html) for this object. So that you can bette control how this instance behaves. For example.

```
class SomeObjectFake {

    private final SomeResponse response;

    public SomeObject(SomeResponse response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public SomeResponse someMethod(Generic<TypeA, TypeB> arg) {
        // Decide what to return
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - so simple and easy!